# How to get my javascript function to display on page load

Tags: javascript, function, onload, countdown

I have found the following script that I would like to edit and use, however i cannot seem to find out how to make the script run and display when a webpage is loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ab78/4/

```
function ShowTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = 18-now.getHours();
  var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
      timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
  $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

;
function StopTime() {
    clearInterval(countdown);

}

ShowTime();
var countdown = setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
```

Above is the link to the jsfiddle. As you can see its a simple countdown timer. I have tried using a body onload="" function, but im left scratching my head a bit. I am not very good with code so any help is appreciated. I have tried writing the function within script tags and putting the div inside the body but I really cannot get the timer to display on the webpage.

Thankyou in advanced!

Comment: It seems to work just fine in the posted fiddle ?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: the timer runs in the fiddle, but I want to call it inside a div on a webpage and it isn't showing anything

Comment: Please provide more of your real markup, given the fiddle works just fine, we can't help you more until we actually see the problem.

Comment: The simplest way is to wrap the whole thing in `window.onload = function() { your code here }`. It works in your fiddle because you selected `onLoad` in the left col and the fiddle did the wrapping for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8Ab78/205/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your jsfiddle is working fine so the problem must be that you are unable to make everything work in a single html file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

    function ShowTime() {
          var now = new Date();
          var hrs = 18-now.getHours();
          var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
          var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();
          timeLeft = hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
          $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
    }

    function StopTime() {
        clearInterval(countdown);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="var countdown = setInterval(function(){ShowTime()} ,1000);">
    <div id="countdown"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I don't see why this shouldn't work, but when I host this as a phtml page on my web server it doesn't display the timer. I can inspect and see the code fine.

Comment: if you run it with html extension is it working then?

Comment: I thought that was going to be a face palm moment then but sadly not.

Comment: I will mark this as answered as it was what I was asking for and "should" work. Will keep going anyway. Thankyou

Comment: did you try different browsers? also did you try running the page locally? Are you  sure you copied/pasted everything correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why the body onload did not work for you but as you seem to be using jQuery you could try to wrap the method call in $(document).ready():

```
var countdown;

function ShowTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hrs = 18-now.getHours();
    var mins = 60-now.getMinutes();
    var secs = 60-now.getSeconds();

    timeLeft = "" +hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds';
    $("#countdown").html(timeLeft);
}

function StopTime() {
    clearInterval(countdown);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ShowTime();
    countdown = setInterval(ShowTime ,1000);
})
```